# Injecting Model into core block module

Tags: magento2, blocks, model, core, di

I want to inject Model into core block module. That it's a simple thing to do in the wrong way (Editing core block). But i want to know how to do it in the right way. Because i want to retrieve User data in the main page.

So, how can i do it, without editing core files?

Im customizing my templates and i want to show users name into the main page, `Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml.`

To do that i need to inyect `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`, the answer is where?

For now i have into grid.phtml the follwing code :

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $name = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session')
          ->getCustomer()->getName();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject customer model file into your block using `__consturct()` function.

```
public function __construct(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
        ) {
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        }

    public function myCustom(){
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! , i think my problem is how to put my block available to use in index page. And not in my own route.

Comment: please check i have updated answer.

Comment: Now i want to pass block to my own custom template. I have into cms_index_index.xml 

<block class="ObjectOut\Objeto\Block\Main" name="object_test" template=" " /> 

So how can i access to grid.phtml, that is in Magento_CatalogWidget inside my custom theme. To pass it into <block ... template="" >

Comment: yes you can call function directly inside your template file

Comment: please let me know if you have query

Comment: I'm just using getName from \Magento\Customer\Model\Session  method.

Inside <block> tag inside me layout file, what is the route to access the template inside  app/code/design/frontend/theme/owntheme/Magento_CataloWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

Thanks again.

Comment: You have to use $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()

Comment: Already using it, and it works just fine. But the only problem left is, i want to have access to that block from a existing template called grid.phtml.

Comment: You can call any block in any template file using, $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Modulename\Block\Customer')->getCustomfunction();

Comment: Excellent! Problem solve then.

Thank you.

Comment: You can click on true sign in left side of my answer below 0 arrow.

Comment: Thanks., Each time you can accept answer for your question and upvote or downvote using click arrow in left of each user answer. So accepted answer is useful for new community user

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1 you'd get someone's session using:

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')`

From there if you want to set a variable you can use:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
$session->setVariableName('yourvalue')
```

And to retrieve your variable

```
$session->getVariableName();
```

Comment: Thanks! But i am working with Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

core/session is not present in Magento2. There are these ones:

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session
\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session
```

You need to inject an instance of the session you need in your block.
Let's take for example \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session.

```
protected $catalogSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    ....
){
    ....
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use the catalog session inside the class like this:

```
$this->catalogSession->setMyValue('test_value');
$this->catalogSession->getMyValue();
```

*Hope it helps*

Comment: I get that, but in which file i should inyect \Magento\Customer\Model\Session ? Thanks